# Security between microservices layers

Tags: security, microservices

I've read a lot about microservices, but one question remain : the security.

What I would like to do is something similar to Netflix, i.e one general backend and many backends for each front end (for example mobile devices, desktop app, ...).

On the top of that I plan to put my firewall security layer. Here is the problem : how to authorize a request through this layer only once and not in each microservice ?

Is is possible to expose certain microservices to the whole internet, and others only to trusted sources ? If so, is it the right way ?

Comment: This is called zoning (DMZ) - you can have a public zone, where all the services that are exposed to the internet reside and a private zone which can only communicate with itself and with the machines in the public zone. More on DMZ can be found in the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've read a lot, but not too much. Please give a look at:

- [Building microservices](http://samnewman.io/books/building_microservices/) (it talks about every aspect of MSs, and also about security)
- [The Practice of Cloud System Administration](http://the-cloud-book.com/) (not strictly MS relatad but containts many useful information)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be assigning a public IP to the microservice you want to expose, and then perhaps have a VPN set-up that trusted entities use to access the other microservices.